# Convert Random Directory to Sequential Directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have such a code but chooses randomly. I want to do this in turn.
What should I do to return the directory in order? Like 1,2,3,4 ...

```js
const activities_list = [
    "with the &help command.", 
    "with the developers console",
    "with some code", 
    "with JavaScript"
    ]; // creates an arraylist containing phrases you want your bot to switch through.

client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1); // generates a random number between 1 and the length of the activities array list (in this case 5).
        client.user.setActivity(activities_list[index]); // sets bot's activities to one of the phrases in the arraylist.
    }, 10000); // Runs this every 10 seconds.
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1); // generates a random number between 1 and the length of the activities array list (in this case 5).
  client.user.setActivity(activities_list[index]); // sets bot's activities to one of the phrases in the arraylist.
}, 10000); // Runs this every 10 seconds.
```

To this:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  client.user.setActivity(activities_list[0]);
  activities_list.push(activities_list.shift());
}, 10_000);
```